# Google+ PHP page state error

Tags: php, google-plus

I just started a new google compute vm with a LAMP stack and put the google+ api quickstart files on it. I replaced my client secret and id as expected, but the page is not displaying any info about my friends, it does display my profile info correctly however. I checked the console and I am getting an error like this:

```
http://MY_IP//connect?state={{%20STATE%20}}
```

I think it is coming from this line in connect server but Im not sure how to fix it:

```
url: window.location.href + '/connect?state={{ STATE }}',
```

As a side note I had to add my client id to the index.html page in order to get that far, though I was under the impression that I only had to add it to the signin.php page when following these examples: https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/php